# Docker remove container error

Tags: docker

When I want to rerun container with another volumes or update image.
I stop and try to remove container, but often geterror on `rm` command

```
# docker rm containername

Error response from daemon: Driver devicemapper failed to remove root filesystem dbe6....f91f: Device is Busy
```

I need to restart docker daemon to remove container.

```
~ # docker version                                                                                                           root@CentOS-72-64-minimal
    Client:
     Version:      1.12.5
     API version:  1.24
     Go version:   go1.6.4
     Git commit:   7392c3b
     Built:        Fri Dec 16 02:23:59 2016
     OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

    Server:
     Version:      1.12.5
     API version:  1.24
     Go version:   go1.6.4
     Git commit:   7392c3b
     Built:        Fri Dec 16 02:23:59 2016
     OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
    ------------------------------------------------------------
~ # docker info                                                                                                              root@CentOS-72-64-minimal
    Containers: 40
     Running: 11
     Paused: 0
     Stopped: 29
    Images: 32
    Server Version: 1.12.5
    Storage Driver: devicemapper
     Pool Name: docker-8:3-28705145-pool
     Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
     Base Device Size: 10.74 GB
     Backing Filesystem: xfs
     Data file: /dev/loop0
     Metadata file: /dev/loop1
     Data Space Used: 14.83 GB
     Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
     Data Space Available: 92.54 GB
     Metadata Space Used: 21.15 MB
     Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
     Metadata Space Available: 2.126 GB
     Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 10.74 GB
     Udev Sync Supported: true
     Deferred Removal Enabled: false
     Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
     Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
     Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
     WARNING: Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. Use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` to specify a custom block storage device.
     Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
     Library Version: 1.02.135-RHEL7 (2016-09-28)
    Logging Driver: json-file
    Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
    Plugins:
     Volume: local
     Network: bridge overlay host null
    Swarm: inactive
    Runtimes: runc
    Default Runtime: runc
    Security Options: seccomp
    Kernel Version: 3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64
    Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
    OSType: linux
    Architecture: x86_64
    CPUs: 8
    Total Memory: 30.96 GiB
    Name: CentOS-72-64-minimal
    ID: SMTY:72HJ:5QIS:AT63:6GPI:U2UQ:KUYY:C7M6:UIOY:37AR:JS53:JAGA
    Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
    Debug Mode (client): false
    Debug Mode (server): false
    Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
    WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
    WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
    Insecure Registries:
     127.0.0.0/8
```

Comment: Just a simple suggesion, try to reboot the system, or at least restart Docker service.

Comment: yes i mentioned, that restart of docker daemon is the only solution i found for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been experiencing this issue quite a bit on a Red Hat host. The fix according to the reported issue on this is to upgrade to a newer kernel. As a workaround for places where that's not an option, I've been using `docker rm -f ...` which still throws the error but the container does get cleaned up. Much quicker and less intrusive than a restart of the daemon.

Comment: Guess it's best solution, i'm not sure about kernel upgrading for now. I used force remove, but error stopped me from checking if container really removed.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem, `service docker restart` almost always fixes the issue.(restarting docker service)

More information about this issue availbale [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/22260).